# How to add a label inside polygon in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, layout, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin application want to add a label inside a polygon .The label position should be vertically center and horizontally start in the polygon. How to achieve this. Is there any other alternative way for creating this UI.Is it possible to create a Stacklayout like below.

Here is my current code and output

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3">
   <Polygon Points="50 0, 0 100, 800 100, 800 0"
            Fill="{StaticResource PrimaryGray}"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   </Polygon>
    <Label Text="To sdfghuiop retyuiop sdftyguiop sertdyfuio sdtfyguio"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>

 </Grid>
```

The first img is portrait view and the other is landscape
[image]

Comment: You could also try using [Xamarin.Forms AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/).

Let's make a small demo using SkiaSharp. First, you could install **SkiaSharp.Views.Forms** NuGet.

Here is the xaml, we put the **SKCanvasView** into the Grid.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             ...
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms">

.....
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <skia:SKCanvasView Grid.Row="1" PaintSurface="SKCanvasView_PaintSurface" />
</Grid>
```

This is the code behind,

```
void SKCanvasView_PaintSurface(System.Object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
    SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
    canvas.Clear();

    //Draw the polygon
    SKPath path = new SKPath();
    path.MoveTo(0.2f * info.Width, 0.1f * info.Height);
    path.LineTo(0.9f * info.Width, 0.1f * info.Height);
    path.LineTo(0.9f * info.Width, 0.9f * info.Height);
    path.LineTo(0.1f * info.Width, 0.9f * info.Height);
    path.Close();

    SKPaint fillPaint = new SKPaint
    {
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
        Color = SKColors.Gray
    };


    //Draw the text
    string str = "To sdfghuiop retyuiop sdftyguiop sertdyfuio sdtfyguio";

    SKPaint textPaint = new SKPaint
    {
        Color = SKColors.Black
    };

    // Adjust TextSize property so text is 50% of screen width
    float textWidth = textPaint.MeasureText(str);
    textPaint.TextSize = 0.5f * info.Width * textPaint.TextSize / textWidth;

    // Find the text bounds
    SKRect textBounds = new SKRect();
    textPaint.MeasureText(str, ref textBounds);
    float xText = info.Width / 2 - textBounds.MidX;
    float yText = info.Height / 2 - textBounds.MidY;

    

    // draw the polygon and text on the canvas
    canvas.DrawPath(path, fillPaint);
    canvas.DrawText(str, xText, yText, textPaint);
}
```

The related docs,

Draw the polygon: [Integrating Text and Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/text)

Draw the text: [Path Basics in SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/paths)

You may refer to the above docs and make some adjustments to your code based on your demand.

Here is the effect,

[image]